# Next.js 13 DELETE request 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input'

Tags: typescript, http, next.js, fetch, http-delete

I have a web app using Next 13 with a `route.ts` file under the `api` folder that
currently contains 2 different methods **POST** and **DELETE**.

**Both methods receive the request successfully** but when trying to JSON parse the body of the request, it works for the POST but not for the DELETE, even though I'm performing the exact same steps.

I checked the request in the 'Network' tab of the dev tools and the payload is fine.
what am I missing?

This is the Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at NextRequest.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6160:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DELETE (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/workPlace/route.ts:35:22)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:242:37)
```

The DELETE request body should contain a json with one property - array of strings.
**Frontend** as follows:

```
export async function fetchRemoveWorkPlaces(ids: string[]) {
    const data = { ids: ids }
    const response = await fetch(
        '/api/workPlace', 
        {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    )
  }
```

This is the `route.ts` in the server:

```
export async function POST(req: Request, res: NextResponse , context: {}) {
    
    try {
        const body: any = await req.json()
        const response = await workPlaceDao.addWorkPlace(body)

        return NextResponse.json(
            {
                success: true,
                workPlace: response
            }, 
            { status: 200 })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error occurred while Add Work Place Request');
        console.log(e);
        return NextResponse.json({success: false}, { status: 500 })
    }
}
export async function DELETE(req: Request, res: NextResponse , context: {}) {

    try {
        const body: any = await req.json()
        const response = await workPlaceDao.deleteWorkPlace(body.ids)

        return NextResponse.json(
            {
                success: true,
            }, 
            { status: 200 })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error occurred trying to delete Work Places');
        console.log(e);
        return NextResponse.json({success: false}, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is a known bug and has been addressed (though not much progress has been made)**

- You can read more of it here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53882
- For a quick workaround, we just have to do it the old-fashioned way (alias-ing).  In short, the two that can work nicely currently are GET/POST.
- For your hook to call the REST API

```
export async function fetchRemoveWorkPlaces(ids: string[]) {
    const data = { ids: ids }
    const response = await fetch(
        '/api/workPlace2',  // Change it to something similar
        {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    )
  }
```

and then slap the delete code in the newly acquired "POST" request

```
export async function POST(req: Request, res: NextResponse , context: {}) {
    
   try {
        const body: any = await req.json()
        const response = await workPlaceDao.deleteWorkPlace(body.ids)

        return NextResponse.json(
            {
                success: true,
            }, 
            { status: 200 })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error occurred trying to delete Work Places');
        console.log(e);
        return NextResponse.json({success: false}, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE requests usually don't include a body, so you can send the IDs up in query params instead on the frontend:

```js
export async function fetchRemoveWorkPlaces(ids: string[]) {
    const response = await fetch(
        `/api/workPlace?ids=${JSON.stringify(ids)}`, 
        {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        }
    );
}
```

On the server side, read the query parameters instead of trying to parse the body:

```js
export async function DELETE(req: Request, res: NextResponse , context: {}) {

    try {
        const ids: string[] = JSON.parse(req.query.ids as string); // Parse the query parameter

        const response = await workPlaceDao.deleteWorkPlace(ids);

        return NextResponse.json(
            {
                success: true,
            }, 
            { status: 200 });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error occurred trying to delete Work Places');
        console.log(e);
        return NextResponse.json({success: false}, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

Comment: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Request'

Answer (score 0):

in your NextJs frontend:

```js
await axios.delete(`/api/item`, { params: { id } })
```

in your NextJs backend: /api/item/route.ts

```js
export async function DELETE(req: Request) {
  console.log("DELETE", req, req.url);
  const id = req.url.split('=')[1];
  ...
}
```